# Navigating to different views in Single Page Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js, single-page-application

I'm developing Single page web application for which I will be using the MVC and knockout. In the _Layout.cshtml, I will have the menu bar using which user can view different views. When I click on the items in menu, I will be calling controller method and being a single page application, I will have to return partial view. However, I'm confused how I can load returned partial view exactly in my view area. If I use Ajax.BeginForm, I can specify the UpdateTargetID in which I need to update my partial view but as with menu item click, it will just be server method call. So I wonder how I can update the partial view inside view area?

Do you think writing following javascript function for each menu items is what I need to do?

```
$('#menuitemId').click( function() {
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: '@Url.Content("~/ControllerName/ActionName")',
    data: objectToPass,
    success: function (data) {
       $('#divid').innerHTML = data;  // data is partial view returned from controller
    }
});
}
```

Also, can someone point me/share working demo/good documents of Single page web application with MVC and knockout?

Comment: that would do it . yes , `ajax` & `innerHtml` & passing partialview from controller

Comment: url: '@Url.Action("ActionName","ControllerName")', then retuirn partial view on this action

Comment: and if you want sample then VS2013 guves you a prebuilt template of single page application using WebApi and Knockout

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That looks fine to me.
You could also make it simpler like this:

```
$('#menuitemId').click( function() {
   $('#divid').load('@Url.Content("~/ControllerName/ActionName")' + menuItemId);
});
```